# how to change color dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, colors

I want to change my marquee color
Here is Html code

```
<marquee><div id="thakan">Thakaan ka Ant, Shakti Turant!!</div></marquee>
```

And this is the javascript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var col=0;
function changeMarqueeColor()
{
    if(col==0)
    {
        //document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
        documrnt.getElementById("thakan").style.color="yello";
        col=1;
    }
    else
    {
        documrnt.getElementById("thakan").style.color="blue";
        col=0;
    }

}
 b=setInterval("changeMarqueeColor();",500);
</script>
```

You can access this also by visiting this link : http://jsfiddle.net/W4tzf/

Comment: ''document'' not ''documrnt'' shoud do the trick.

Comment: Look at your console before asking a question.

Comment: Wow `marquee` is still alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below works. As others have mentioned, you've misspelled `document`. Also the simplest way to achieve what you want is with `setInterval`, and unquoted function name.

```
var col=0;
function changeMarqueeColor() 
{
    if(col==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("thakan").style.color="red";
        col=1;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("thakan").style.color="blue";
        col=0;
    }
}
setInterval(changeMarqueeColor,500);
```

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled "document", you wrote "documrnt" instead.